# Intermediate field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{17})/\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sigma^8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

$\zeta = \zeta_{17}$. As stated, the set up is looking at $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{17})/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z},$ generated by $\sigma: \zeta \to \zeta^2$. I'm looking for the corresponding subfield of $<\sigma^8>$. Shouldn't it be

$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \sigma^8(\zeta))?$ But $\sigma^8(\zeta) = \zeta^{2^8} = \zeta.$

Surely $\sigma^8$ does not fix the $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Galois group is generated by $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^k$ for $k$ a primitive $17^\text{th}$ root of unity. $2$ is not a primitive $17^\text{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: Hint: $\sigma^8$ is the only element of order two in the Galois group. The usual complex conjugation is an element of this Galois group.